# Problems connecting XMega-A1 Xplained via USB

Tags: python

I am trying to connect a Atmel XMega-A1 Xplained board to the RPi via USB and reading out data with Python (PySerial). OS is Wheezy-Raspbian.
After trying a lot of different things, I'm out of suggestions. Please see if I have forgotten anything.

My question is really just "why can't I open the port?"

This is my Python code:

```
import serial
print "dev" #debug
dev = serial.Serial()
print "settings.." #debug
dev.port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
dev.baudrate = 9600
dev.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
dev.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
dev.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE

print "dev.open():" #debug
dev.open()
print "dev.open() = open!" #debug
value = None
while not value:
        value = dev.readline()
print value
```

This gives me this open error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usb2.py", line 20, in <module>
    dev.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 278, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

I am a member of the dialout group

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/vs $ whoami
pi
pi@raspberrypi ~/vs $ groups
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users netdev input
```

Running the script with or without sudo gives the same outcome.
When connecting the USB this is the outcome of dmesg:

```
[   57.604335] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[   57.707605] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=03eb, idProduct=2122
[   57.707634] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   57.707651] usb 1-1.2: Product: XPLAINED CDC
[   57.707663] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: ATMEL
[   57.707675] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 056007012069
[   57.780344] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[   57.868478] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[   57.868509] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

I followed [this](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_USB_CDC_ACM_and_MS_composite_Linux_gadget_driver) and installed picocom. Output of "picocom /dev/ttyACM0":

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/vs $ picocom /dev/ttyACM0
picocom v1.7

port is        : /dev/ttyACM0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 9600
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv
imap is        :
omap is        :
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,


FATAL: cannot open /dev/ttyACM0: Input/output error
```

Again, sudo makes no difference.

This is my first post so let me know if this is too verbose. Thanks!

Comment: xxmbabanexx: Well, thanks! :)

Update: I've tested my py-code on Windows. It works, and I can read out data. However, if I try to open the port while it's already open I will get the same Error 5.
Like 
`dev = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)
dev = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)`.

But I cannot see that the port is actually already in use on Linux. Have anyone experienced something alike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was with driver modules. 
When I connect the Xmega it automatically detect it as an USB ACM device, and load the cdc_acm driver module.

Unloading the "cdc_acm" module and loading the "usbserial" module solved the communication problem.

```
# Unloading cdc_acm module:
sudo rmmod cdc_acm
# Loading usbserial module:
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x03eb product=0x2122
```

Vendor and product is given via the "lsusb -v" command. 
The port is no longer "/dev/ttyACM0", but "/dev/ttyUSB0".

It's worth noting that every time I connected the Xmega via the USB, the cdc_acm module was automatically loaded by the system. Even after unloading it with the "sudo rmmod cdc_acm". Solving this was not allowed by my time frame, so I made a batch script unloading cdc_acm, loading usbserial and running my python script. It also unloads the usbserial at the beginning, just in case one has already run it:

```
echo "Unloading usbserial module.."
sudo rmmod usbserial
echo "Unloading cdc-acm module.."
sudo rmmod cdc_acm
echo "Loading usbserial module.."
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x03eb product=0x2122
echo "Done.."
python thescript.py
```

Ok. Since no one (at this time) had any ideas, this is how a solved my problem. 
*Please note that I have limited Linux skills, and that this is most likely not the best method (Especially not in the long run).* It did however enable me to do the communication that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To make Linux use the USB serial module instead of the `cdc-acm` module, I made a rule to place in `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

I use a JTAG ICE instead of FLIP to program the board, so I don't need the ACM module.

I named it `93-usb-xmega-A1-xplained.rules`. Its content below:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty" ATTRS{idVendor}=="03eb" ATTRS{idProduct}=="2122" MODE="0666" SYMLINK+="xplained" GROUP=="dialout"
```

As you can see, it makes a symlink. You open `/dev/xplained` with your favorite comm tool.